# Gwt: display Table faster

Tags: performance, gwt, tabular, flextable

I have the problem, that my program is too slow in displaying a flexTable. I've searched how to display the table faster and I think with a cell table it might be faster. The problem now is, there are different objects displayed in the table and I don't know how to do that with a celltable. I have a `list<DTOEmployeeWithTask>` and each `dTOEmployeeWithTask` has a `list<TaskRelation>`. First there's displayed a row with the employee and then each `taskRelation` for the employee, like this:

[image: image of table]

Now to my questions: what is the fastest way to display such a table? If it's with a cellTable, how would I do that in a CellTable?

If you need some code just say what you need.

Answer (score 3):

FlexTable is a no go anyway as it's known to be slow. What would be a good solution is a Custom `DataGrid`, which can display rows with sub rows as in your screenshot. The GWT showcase page has a nice example including source code which should help you further: http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomDataGrid

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will look it up and accept the answer when I'm sure that it is, what I need ;)

Comment: I tried to do it with a dataGrid and this worked, but it's not faster than the flextable... so what now?